# Why is the .config file not copied to /boot after installing new kernel?

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel

I run across such a weird problem:

According to [this](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/Csc521.071/notes/blk.html):

> The kernel and modules must be moved to special locations in order to
>   be used,
>
> ```
> 1. make modules_install
> 2. make install
> ```
>
> The first will create the /lib/modules/ directory and place
>   the modules there. The second make target will,
>
> ```
> 1. Move the kernel, bzImage, to /boot and rename it vmlinuz-<revision>,
> 2. Move the System.map to /boot,
> 3. Create initrd.img-<revision>
> 4. Copy .config to /boot, renaming it to config-<revision>
> 5. Modifies the boot loader configuration file /boot/grub/menu.lst
>    so that the new kernel is listed on the boot menu.
> ```

I configure and compile the latest Linux kernel 3.15, and run `make install` to install the new kernel. Everything seems OK except for the .config file is not copied to `/boot`.

Why is the .config file under the root directory of the source tree not copied to /boot ?

PS. My running OS is fedora 20.

Comment: what is the config file present in /boot? Have you checked all subdirectories of /boot? Grub 2 has a slightly different structure.

Comment: Do you have the `/proc/config.gz` file on your system? This one could be enough to compile new kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document appears to be incorrect or long-obsolete. Looking at the [source](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/boot/Makefile), I see only `bzImage` and `System.map` being copied. This was the case at least as far back as [2.6.12](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/arch/i386/boot/Makefile?id=1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2). Copying an `initrd` or the `.config` file would have to be done by a distribution's scripts.

For some reason this depends on the architecture: [arm](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/Makefile) and [x86](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/boot/Makefile) don't copy `.config`, but [mips](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/mips/Makefile) and [tile](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/tile/Makefile) do.