# why .config file doesn't appear in /boot after installation kernel 4.8.8

Tags: centos, kernel, boot, linux-kernel

I've already seen this [Why is the .config file not copied to /boot after installing new kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128634/why-is-the-config-file-not-copied-to-boot-after-installing-new-kernel) but the question weren't answered ! 
I've installed the new kernel and everything seems to be running smoothly. But there's no .config file in /boot

why this happens??[image]

I'm running CentoeS 7.2.1511

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the kernel you can suppress the generation of the `.config` file .

You should ask this question to the mantainer/s of that package, the fact that the `.config` should always be there is a common misconception about the linux kernel, mostly because all the major distributions leave the `.config` file be, but there are many developers, especially in the embedded and server world, that suppress it .

Comment: you mean that my new configuration hasn't been created?? or it's been made but it isn't shown in /boot ??

Comment: @Kasra you haven't specified where this new kernel is coming from, if you are the one that is building from the sources you should check the `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` and `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` options, you probably should check `/proc/config.gz` and / or `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config` too and see if it's there .

Comment: I've downloaded my new kernel from https://www.kernel.org/ in .xz extenssion

Comment: @Kasra ok, I have given you hints about what to check to try to justify the missing `.config` under `/boot`

Comment: are the options that you mentioned above shown during the `make menuconfig` process??

Comment: @Kasra with `menuconfig` you can use the search option by pressing `/` but usually `grep IKCONFIG .config` ( given inside the kernel tree after you have configured it ) is enough to check if a flag is on or off .

Comment: @Kasra check the 2 files that I have mentioned above in my 2nd comment too